# how to connect Power BI service to google cloud storage (Bucket)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, powerbi, bucket

I was working with Azure Blob Storage, where I stored some csv files. I then build some dashboards on PowerBI using those csv files.
The connection between Power BI and Azure Blob storage is easy going. 
Now I want to use the same concept, but only replacing Azure Blob Storage with Google Cloud Storage Bucket(GCS-B).
My problem is, I can't connect Power BI to GCS-B. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After a long googling, documentation reading... There is What I got.
- The only way to connect Power BI service to google cloud storage, is by running a Virtual machine as a Getway, then running some script inside this virtual machine that get the data from gcs and then load it to power bi. I think this is not a useful way to do it.
- What I tried and it works fine, but unfortunately only for power BI desktop is the following R script. That I run in power Bi as data source option:

```
wd <-getwd()
setwd(wd)
file.create("service_account.json")
json <- '{"type": "service_account",
          "project_id": "xxxxxxx",
          "private_key_id": "xxxxx"
          "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\n...
           ...}'
write(json, "service_account.json")
write(j, "service_account.json")
options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud- 
platform")
library(googleCloudStorageR)
Sys.setenv("GCS_AUTH_FILE" = "service_account.json")
### optional, if you haven't set environment argument GCS_AUTH_FILE
gcs_auth()
gcs_global_bucket("xxxxx")
gcs_get_global_bucket()
df <- gcs_get_object(gcs_list_objects()$name[[1]])
```

with this script you can load the first csv file from the specified bucket to power BI desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the bucket or the object public, how to do it read [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public):
Than copy link from each file (column Public access) and add it to Power Bi like Web source.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include some context and the essential parts of the answer here, then provide the link for reference. Link-only answers become invalid when the linked page changes or goes offline. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.